# Configuring the pretty printing for all objects in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter seems to have some built-in pretty printing, via the `lib.pretty` submodule. However, I would like to configure the default printing by introducing a depth limit to the display, so that complex nested dictionaries are truncated. I can do this using Python's [`pprint.PrettyPrinter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter), but it's not clear to me how I can tell Jupyter to always use this printer when asked to display Python objects.

The [ipython docs here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html?highlight=pretty#pretty-printing) describe how individual classes can be customized to have custom print logic, but I actually want my custom printer to be used for everything.

How can I do this with Jupyter?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can register a formatter for `object`, which will affect everything that is displayed by Jupyter. However you have to do so separately for all the MIME types you want to target:

```py
import pprint

for key in ["text/html", "text/markdown"]:
    get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters[key].for_type(
        object,
        lambda x: pprint.pformat(x, depth=2)
    )
```

You can of course change `pprint.pformat` to any pretty printing function you want.